# returning a function returning bool VS returning bool (OCaml)

Tags: function, ocaml

```
type form = TRUE
    |FALSE
    |NOT of form

let rec check x = function
    TRUE            -> true
    |FALSE          -> false
    |NOT(y)         -> not eval y
(*where TRUE, FALSE and NOT all custom type 'form'*)
```

I tried to define a function form -> bool, but I got an compile error for

```
    |NOT(y)         -> not eval y
```

line. The error message says

```
This expression type form  -> bool, but an expression was expected of type bool
```

though the function 'eval' returns type 'bool', what's the reason it can't be a return value for a function returning bool?

Comment: Don't forget, functions are binding to the left, so better write  `not (eval y)`

Answer (score 1):

The type of the function you defined (`check` or `eval`) is `'a -> form -> bool`. You match against implicit input parameter introduced by `function` keyword. First parameter `x` is not used (but expected).

As `eval` has two input parameters, `(eval y)` expression has type `form -> bool`. This is what the error message about.

Try this:

```
let rec eval = function
  | TRUE   -> true
  | FALSE  -> false
  | NOT(y)  -> not (eval y)
```

Alternative form with explicit input parameter `x`:

```
let rec eval x = match x with
  | TRUE   -> true
  | FALSE  -> false
  | NOT(y)  -> not (eval y)
```